# Creating columns in one dataframe based on the values of a column in another dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import datetime

# intialise data of lists. 
data = {'group'      :["A","A","A","B","B","B","B"],
        'val': ["AA","AB","AC","B1","B2","AA","AB"],
        'cal1'     :[4,5,7,6,5,8,9],
        'cal2'     :[10,100,100,10,1,10,100]
       } 

# Create DataFrame 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df1

    group   val cal1    cal2
0   A       AA  4       10
1   A       AB  5       100
2   A       AC  7       100
3   B       B1  6       10
4   B       B2  5       1
5   B       AA  8       10
6   B       AB  9       100

import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import datetime

# intialise data of lists. 
data = {'group'      :["A","A","A","B","B","B","B"],
        'flag' : [1,0,0,1,0,0,0],
        'var1': [1,2,3,7,8,9,10]
       } 

# Create DataFrame 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df2

   group   flag var1
0   A       1   1
1   A       0   2
2   A       0   3
3   B       1   7
4   B       0   8
5   B       0   9
6   B       0   10
```

Step 1: CReate columns in df2 based on unique "val" in df1 like below:

```
unique_val = df1['val'].unique().tolist()
new_cols = [t + '_new' for t in unique_val]
for i in new_cols:
    df2[i] = 0
df2
    group   flag    var1    AA_new  AB_new  AC_new  B1_new  B2_new
0   A       1       1       0       0       0       0        0
1   A       0       2       0       0       0       0        0
2   A       0       3       0       0       0       0        0
3   B       1       7       0       0       0       0        0
4   B       0       8       0       0       0       0        0
5   B       0       9       0       0       0       0        0
6   B       0       10      0       0       0       0        0
```

Step 2: for row where flag = 1, AA_new will be calculated as var1(from df2)* value of 'cal1' from df1 for group "A" and val "AA" * value of 'cal2' from df1 for group "A" and val "AA", similarly AB_new will be calculated as var1(from df2) * value of 'cal1' from df1 for group "A" and val "AB" * value of 'cal2' from df1 for group "A" and val "AB"

My expected output should look like below:

```
    group   flag    var1    AA_new  AB_new  AC_new  B1_new  B2_new
0   A       1       1       40      500     700     0        0
1   A       0       2       0       0       0       0        0
2   A       0       3       0       0       0       0        0
3   B       1       7       570     6300    0       420      35
4   B       0       8       0       0       0       0        0
5   B       0       9       0       0       0       0        0
6   B       0       10      0       0       0       0        0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table) with [`GroupBy.bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.bfill.html) an then we can use [`DataFrame.mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html).

```
df2.assign(**df1.pivot_table(columns='val',
                             values='cal',
                             index = ['group', df2.index])
                .add_suffix('_new')
                .groupby(level=0)
               #.apply(lambda x: x.bfill().ffill()) #maybe neccesary instead bfill
                .bfill()
                .reset_index(level='group',drop='group')
                .fillna(0)
                .mul(df2['var1'], axis=0)
                .where(df2['flag'].eq(1), 0)
               #.astype(int) # if you want int
)
```

**Output**

```
  group  flag  var1  AA_new  AB_new  AC_new  B1_new  B2_new
0     A     1     1     4.0     5.0     7.0     0.0     0.0
1     A     0     2     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
2     A     0     3     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
3     B     1     7    56.0    63.0     0.0    42.0    35.0
4     B     0     8     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
5     B     0     9     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
6     B     0    10     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
```

**EDIT**

```
df2.assign(**df1.assign(mul_cal = df1['cal1'].mul(df1['cal2']))
                .pivot_table(columns='val',
                             values='mul_cal',
                             index = ['group', df2.index])
                .add_suffix('_new')
                .groupby(level=0)
               #.apply(lambda x: x.bfill().ffill()) #maybe neccesary instead bfill
                .bfill()
                .reset_index(level='group',drop='group')
                .fillna(0)
                .mul(df2['var1'], axis=0)
                .where(df2['flag'].eq(1), 0)
               #.astype(int) # if you want int
)


  group  flag  var1  AA_new  AB_new  AC_new  B1_new  B2_new
0     A     1     1    40.0   500.0   700.0     0.0     0.0
1     A     0     2     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
2     A     0     3     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
3     B     1     7   560.0  6300.0     0.0   420.0    35.0
4     B     0     8     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
5     B     0     9     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
6     B     0    10     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
```

Comment: What if I have to calculate on two columns. Updated the question

Comment: Check the EDIT section, try not to change your question many times, it is better to ask several separate questions. Otherwise some solutions could be voted negative after you update the question.

Comment: this doesnot work in a scenario where dataframe df2 has different no of rows as compared to df1.  I have asked a separate question here "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60782098/creating-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-a-column-value-in-other-datafram"